# javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am having trouble debugging this page in IE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    vertical: false,
    scroll: 1,
});
});
```

It works just fine in chrome and firefox. IE it is 100% broken. Any ideas?
(I am using IE9)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? What errors are you getting? What's the code that causes the issue? These are all details you left out of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's an extra coma that doesn't play nice in IE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: false,
        scroll: 1,
    });
});
```

At the and of `scroll: 1,`.

Comment: Thank you! My next question is how did you find that so fast? Do you know why the JS console in FF did not pick that up and tell me about it?

Comment: @joshmmo yes, press F12 in IE for developer tools, which has console that shows you error.

Comment: Also that does not seem to be the only thing. When you click on an image a lightbox comes up with a video. It is still not working in IE but works in other browsers.

Comment: @joshmmo: you can also get to the debugging console through `ALT+X > Developer Tools`

Comment: @joshmmo: I don't see that behavior in Chrome though, at least not in the link you provided.

Comment: Hmm sorry you are correct. It only works in FF. Any ideas why? I do not see any more errors in the JS console.

Comment: @joshmmo: Actually I'm not seeing that behavior in FF either :P. I'm using FF 11.0.

Comment: IE really does a good job of enforcing correctness in JS. It will fail on the trailing comma {'aaa','bbb',} where FF and Chrome will ignore the error. It's sometimes maddening to find the problem, but once you do your code is better for it.

Comment: Errr sorry I seemed to have changed something that caused it to stop working (the video pop up). Let me fix that